# Extracting data passed with jQuery post Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make simple script using jquery $post function to pass data to my check.php file and then just get some result back so I can figure out the way data is manipulated b/w jQuery and PHP.
I have this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var Status = true;
    $('.isLogged').click(function(){
        if(Status!=false){
            var Check = prompt('Enter Password', '');
                $.post('check.php', Check, function(data) { 
        if(data == 'Y'){
            alert('Y');
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            alert('N');
            return false;
        }
        });

      }

  });

}); 
</script>
```

and this is all from my check.php file:

```
<?php
$data = $_POST['Check'];
if ($data == 'Ivan')
{
echo 'Y';
}
else
{
echo 'N';
}
?>
```

but it's not working and when I make var_dump($_POST) I get array(0). How can I fix this?

Thanks

Leron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"data" in $.post function must be a object

```
$.post('check.php', {Check: Check}, function(data) {
```

Answer (score 1):

you should add json in your process.

:)

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed that. I should JSON thr response from check.php right? How should I get back the info, obv. echo is not correct here..?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is not correct for ajax request. `Check` is the value, you must set key for it. Should be like this

```
   var Check = prompt('Enter Password', '');
   $.post('check.php', Check:Check, function(data) {
```